# How to combine strings and make a int to print a value already set

Tags: python

I want to combine this 2 strings and make a "path" for object800 to print the value

```
x = 'object'

y = '800'


object800 = 1000


a = (x + y)

print(int(a)) # i want to print 1000
```

Comment: I'm curious what the possible need for this is. Is this just purely for experimentation?

Comment: Don't do this. There is almost certainly never a good reason to do this

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should use `eval`.

```py
x = 'object'
y = '800'
object800 = 1000
a = eval(x + y)
print(a)
```

Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_eval.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should use `globals`:

```py
x = 'object'
y = '800'

object800 = 1000

print(globals()[x + y])
# Outputs 1000
```

Note that this won't work inside a function, for example:

```
x = 'object'
y = '800'

def func():
    object800 = 1000
    print(globals()[x + y]) 
    # Raises KeyError: 'object800'
    
func()
```

If that's the case, you should use a different approach:

```py
x = 'object'
y = '800'

def func():
    object800 = 1000
    
    varname = x + y
    print(globals()[varname] if varname in globals() else locals()[varname]) 
    # Outputs 1000
    
func()
```